# Getting username with user id in Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I currently have a leaderboard set up, but I'm trying to get the username of top 10 users in a server, but I'm having trouble converting a user ID to the username.

Firstly, I use a for loop to loop through each user within my database:

```
for(let userID of Object.keys(userdata[message.guild.id].users)){
```

My JSON file looks something like this:

```
"83xxxxxxxxxx90": { //server ID
        "users": {
            "24xxxxxxxxxxxx64": { //user ID
                "count": [
                    16,
                    5,
                    2,
                    10,
                    10
                ],
                "username": "username#0001"
            },
            "70xxxxxxxxxxxxxx63": { //second user ID
                "count": [
                    15,
                    4,
                    4,
                    1,
                    12
                ],
                "username": "username#0002"
            },
```

The problem is when I use `client.user.cache.get()`, the .get() part is not recognized, and I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined` error.

For comparison, I ran these two lines of code side by side, but only the second line gave an error:

```
console.log(client.users.cache.get(message.author.id).tag);
console.log(client.users.cache.get(userID).tag);
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I did some more testing and figured out the error was because `client.user.cache.get(userID)` would return an undefined user, while `client.user.cache.get(message.author.id)` would not. Anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `.tag` directly from `author` just do `message.author.tag`

Comment: I have a list of user IDs that I need to convert into usernames/tag. This would not work as that will only provide me the tag of the author of the last message sent.

Comment: then you need get user and fetch it